# Draw ListView column headers separators?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview, user-controls

I'm trying to draw the column headers of a Listview in `details` mode.

This code:

```
Public Sub Me_DrawColumnHeader(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs) _
Handles Me.DrawColumnHeader

    e.DrawDefault = False ' Set ownerdraw.

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.SteelBlue, e.Bounds)
    e.DrawText()

End Sub
```

Produces this:

[image: http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/8150/k5nm.jpg]

But I would like to draw the vertical separator lines like windows does:

[image: http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/7185/1iz9.jpg]

> UPDATE:

I found a way to draw them:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Right)
```

But seems that does not have the same anchor.

also notice that my header text is too close of the separator lines and also are upper than the original windows listview:

Compare them:

Own:

[image]

Original:

[image]

This is the code that I'm using to draw the text:

```
    e.DrawDefault = False ' Set ownerdraw.

    Dim strFormat As New StringFormat()

    If e.Header.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center Then
        strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    ElseIf e.Header.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right Then
        strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    End If

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 147, 73)), e.Bounds)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, strFormat)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Right)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the *.DrawBackground* and *.DrawText* methods of the `DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs` renders without visual styles:

```
e.DrawDefault = False  ' Set ownerdraw.


'BACKGROUND

Using brush As Brush = New SolidBrush(e.BackColor)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds)
End Using

Dim bounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds

bounds.Width -= 1
bounds.Height -= 1

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(SystemPens.ControlDarkDark, bounds)

bounds.Width -= 1
bounds.Height -= 1

e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ControlLightLight, bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Right, bounds.Y)
e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ControlLightLight, bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.X, bounds.Bottom)
e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ControlDark, (bounds.X + 1), bounds.Bottom, bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom)
e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ControlDark, bounds.Right, (bounds.Y + 1), bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom)

'TEXT

Dim textAlign As HorizontalAlignment = e.Header.TextAlign
Dim flags As TextFormatFlags = If((textAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left), TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding, If((textAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center), TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter, TextFormatFlags.Right))

'(I added this line)
flags = (flags Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)

Dim text As String = e.Header.Text
Dim width As Integer = TextRenderer.MeasureText(" ", e.Font).Width
bounds = Rectangle.Inflate(e.Bounds, -width, 0)
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, [text], e.Font, bounds, e.ForeColor, flags)
```

Comment: It's a flexible solution to customize all the things, thanks so much